# Можно ли с помощью Gitlab запустить bash-скрипт на сервере?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

В целом задача проста и понятна. Нужно чтобы при пуше в ветку мастер на сервере запускался один bash-скрипт, при пуше в ветку qa - другой.
Можно ли это реализовать средствами gitlab? (!Важно - не веб-хуком).
Если да то как? Опишите что за чем делать. Если нет, то каким способом это можно сделать?

Comment: Если важно не вебхуком, то было бы неплохо пояснить почему

Comment: тогда остается GitLab CI юзать и дергать там нужные скрипты на сервере нужном

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, здорово) а вы можете пример показать? самый простой, который просто дернет sh.

Comment: @sanu0074 а у вас на unix системе установлен гитлаб ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator да. Тестовый стенд на этом же сервере что и гитлаб. Грубо говоря нужно дернуть скрипт который лежит на том же сервере на котором гитлаб установлен

Comment: @sanu0074 покажите как вы запускаете скрипт

Comment: @sanu0074 вообще, это новый вопрос, который требует другого решения. нужно было создавать новый вопрос. не стесняйтесь задавать вопросы!

Comment: Вот этот forever? https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, этот

Comment: Вопрос про то, как на разных ветках разные скрипты выполнять? Или о том, где взять `node` и `forever`?

Comment: Ага, понял. Вы сильно поменяли вопрос. Не стоит так делать, лучше новый задать (на него я вам тоже отвечу наверняка)

Comment: @NickVolynkin в данный момент про Node и Forever. Сейчас актуально создавать отдельный вопрос? Или лучше пусть уже тут все остается?

Comment: @sanu0074 конечно, нужен новый, вопрос же совершенно другой. Этот вроде бы про то, как на разных ветках выполнять разные задачи.

Comment: @NickVolynkin создал: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626158/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-gitlab-runner

Comment: @sanu0074 у вас получилось `.gitlab-ci.yml` приспособить?

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, срабатывает в нужный момент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запускать разные скрипты для ветки `master` и для всех остальных можно с помощью директив `except` и `only`. Вот пример файла `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: ...

stages:
  - build

build_branch:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./build_branch.sh
  except:
    - master

build_master:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./build_master.sh
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 1):

можно запустить сценарий на CI GitLab, а внутри этих сценарий выполнять то, что хотим

перейти во вкладку `Project` -> `Set up CI`  и добавить сценарий

```
run_job_with_some_name:
  stage: myStage
  script:
    - uname -a
    - pwd
    - "your some command"
```

более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#script)

Comment: в общем, написал я скрипт. У меня появились проблемы с командами при выполнении скрипта из раннера. Обновил вопрос, взгляните.