# Ошибка при выполнении Gitlab runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Есть раннер который срабатывает при пуше, он должен выполнить скрипт который расположен на сервере на котором расположен сам гитлаб.

Скрипт выглядит так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

forever stop "myproject"

cd /myproject

export NODE_PATH=.
export NODE_ENV=qa
export NODE_INIT_TARGET=build

node --use_strict bin/init

forever start -a --uid "myproject" --minUptime 20000 --spinSleepTime 20000 bin/start --use_strict
```

т.е. он просто должен запустить js-скрипт который сначала уберет процесс из forever.js (остановив этим приложение), соберет фронт, потом добавит процесс в forever.js (запустит приложение). Так то если руками в консоли запускать - все работает. А вот раннер выдает такую ошибку:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.10.4 (b32125f)
Using Shell executor...
Running on server...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 5553b27 Merge branch 'dev' into 'master'
Checking out ed68665c as dev...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ /myproject/myScript.sh
/myproject/myScript.sh: строка 3: forever: команда не найдена
/myproject/myScript.sh: строка 11: node: команда не найдена
/myproject/myScript.sh: строка 13: forever: команда не найдена
ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

В чем может быть причина?

```
root@server:/node_data/csgo-forecast/bin# env
PATH=/home/sanu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

root@server:/node_data/csgo-forecast/bin# sudo -iu gitlab-runner bash -c set
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это означает, что у вас не установлены или недоступны нужные зависимости.

```
/myproject/myScript.sh: строка 3: forever: команда не найдена
/myproject/myScript.sh: строка 11: node: команда не найдена
```

Shell Runner работает под учёткой `gitlab-runner`. Похоже, что ей недоступны node и forever. Возможно, в `PATH` нет нужных директорий — сравните его с `PATH` на той учётке, под которой у вас всё успешно запускается вручную. Также возможно, что нужно запускать из-под привилегированной учетки.

Подробнее: [Running as unprivileged user](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html#running-as-unprivileged-user)

(Да, это ещё не ответ, но в комментарий уже не входит. Буду дополнять ответ по мере появления подробностей.)

Comment: ♦ `root@server:/node_data/csgo-forecast/bin# env`
PATH=/home/sanu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
`root@server:/node_data/csgo-forecast/bin# sudo -iu gitlab-runner bash -c set` 
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Я не пойму где тут пути к forever и node?

Comment: @sanu0074 `which forever; which node`. Оба лежат где-то в этих путях.

Comment: Скорее всего в `/home/sanu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin`

Comment: Я добавил в `/home/gitlab-runner/.bashrc`
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" 
Но PATH этого юзера не изменилась. Подскажите как изменить переменную юзеру gitlab-runner?

Comment: Дело действительно в переменной, я ее руками в скрипте засеттил руками там где export NODE_ENV и NODE_PATH, теперь он нашел forever и node. Но теперь появились ошибки при обращении к файлам в приложении: `error: [/myproject/core/lib/build/interceptors/index.js]  Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'gen/interceptors/index.js'
    at Error (native)
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'core/logs/info.log'
    at Error (native)` Это что-то с правами я так полагаю?

Comment: Я разобрался. Добавил sudo в yml файл и разрешил юзеру gitlab-runner выполнять sudo без ввода пароля. Но вопрос с PATH так и остался, т.к. так делать некрасиво: `export PATH=/home/sanu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin:/usr/local/sbi\u200c\u200bn:/usr/local/bin:/us\u200c\u200br/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbi\u200c\u200bn:/bin 
export NODE_PATH=.
export NODE_ENV=qa
export NODE_INIT_TARGET=build`

Comment: @sanu0074 Похоже, дальше я вам не подскажу. Надо бы разобраться, как всё правильно делать с shell runner'ом — а я в основном с docker runner'ом работал.

Comment: Спасибо, попытаюсь разобраться)

Comment: @sanu0074 если найдёте ответ  — опубликуйте, с меня плюс.